# Push notifications disappear instantly

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any reason why a push notification would appear on the lock screen and then instantly disappear? I am using the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` block to save data in the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your completionHandler code is setting the number of notifications to 0 ? That would make it disappear.

Comment: Based on some testing in my app, manually setting the badge number to _any_ number, not just 0, will cause the notification to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Either you put the number of notifications to 0 in your code like

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

Or in you Notification payload, you have a the badge property set to 0

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 0,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
}
```